# Remove alpha from Photoshop layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

I'm wondering if there's an solid way (not a hack) to remove transparency from a photoshop layer? I know the usual, hacky way is to duplicate and merge a layer around 8 times or more to reach a fully opaque result (with the exception of areas with 100% transparency). But this just doesn't sound right, maybe there's an option to do this without such a convulted method that I don't know about.

Here's an example:

[image: Transparency]
[image: Removed transparency]

Comment: Can you add some before/after images to your post? I have a hard time envisioning what you are asking: removing alpha **but** not by filling it with a color? What should there be instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a mistake on my part, should've made myself clearer. I meant not fill it with any other color that the ones already in the image. I've edited the question to reflect that and I'll post images shortly.

Comment: Since transparency is present in both versions, I wonder if the reference is to the "feather" surrounding the colored area?

Comment: Kind of, I would describe it as removing partial transparency? it really doesn't matter if the background is transparent or white as long as whatever color information present is retained rather than faded to white as it happens when you "Flatten" the layers. Edited question once again for clarity.

Comment: If for any reason that other question doesn't solve it for you please ask a new question specifying what you tried and why it didn't work sufficiently for you. There's no simple solution for this but depending on the end goal there's a lot of possible methods to use.

Comment: Hi ryan, in that question OP specifically says that duplicating layers doesn't work for what he needs. While I'm looking to know if there's an actual photoshop function to do precisely what duplicating layers does.